# PHP IMAP not working, installed with Macports

Tags: php, imap, macports

I recently installed PHP5 with Macports using `sudo port install php5 +imap`. However, when I run `/opt/local/bin/php -i`, I don't see the IMAP module listed under the other modules. Is there an additional step or change I need to make to php.ini or otherwise to get this module enabled?

Also, running `/usr/bin/php -i` (I believe this is the php NOT installed by Macports) also does not show IMAP configured.

Comment: Yes, `/usr/bin/php` is provided directly from Apple and not installed by MacPorts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP modules have been available as variants in previous versions of the php5 port, but have been moved into their own ports long time ago. You can see the available variants with `port variants php5`, which does not list that +imap anymore. Most probably you followed an oudated tutorial.

To get the IMAP module install the port php5-imap:

```
sudo port install php5-imap
```